# Batch find and replace chars in string

Tags: batch-file, search, replace, scripting

I have two string variables:

```batch
@echo off
set string_1=abc def ghj
set string_2=abc_def_ghj
```

In `string_1` I need to replace spaces with `%20`, so the result will be:

```
abc%20def%20ghj
```

In `string_2` I need to replace `_` with spaces, so the result will be:

```
abc def ghj
```

I need to use batch (.bat) file, what are the options to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) to replace the characters you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "string_1=abc def ghj"
set string_2=abc_def_ghj

set new_string_1=!string_1: =%%20!
set new_string_2=%string_2:_= %

echo Old String 1: %string_1%
echo New String 1: %new_string_1%
echo Old String 2: %string_2%
echo New String 2: %new_string_2%
pause
```

I had to enable delayed expansion in string 1 so that the inner and outer percent signs wouldn't cancel each other out.

Answer (score 2):

[Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) with minimalized [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) scope:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

set "string_1=1abc def ghj"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  set "string_1=!string_1: =%%20!"
ENDLOCAL&set "string_1=%string_1%"
echo %string_1%

set "string_2=2abc_def_ghj"
set "string_2=%string_2:_= %"
echo %string_2%
```

Note `ENDLOCAL&set "string_1=%string_1%"` line (and *do not change* it).

Output:

```
==>30087503.bat
1abc%20def%20ghj
2abc def ghj
```